# Where can I download VS Code 1.0?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I like old software and try to download VS Code 1.0.0 but archive.org doesn't have a copy. If someone could put a usable official download link that would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out previous releases on the [official repo](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode)

Here's a link to release [1.0.0](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/releases/tag/1.0.0)

Comment: No is's a binary I want

Comment: You can build a binary from the source. You have to do that if you want out of date releases.